# How to make select options in Rails that point to URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a select menu whose options simply point to URLs:

```
# Ruby:
form_tag "", :method => 'get' do
  select_tag "", options_for_select([["Memberships", memberships_url], ["Transactions", transactions_url]])
end

# jQuery:
$('form').on('change', function() {
  $(this).submit();
});
```

However, this isn't working. What am I missing?

Comment: Selects and options are not meant for this. What you want is a drop down that actually provides links. For example, check out how [Bootstrap does theirs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

Comment: is there more to this?  memberships_url is probably just a string? maybe try making it populate an <a> tag or something?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"? Are you expecting navigation when the select box changes? If so you would need to implement a `javascript` or `jQuery` hook for the `onchange` event and then redirect based on value.

Comment: @engineersmnky: I have that jQuery hook actually.

Comment: @MrDanA: You are perfectly right. However, in this case I really need a select box to serve as the menu.

Comment: you should post the code then because I am unsure how you are implementing this hook without any identifiers for the form or the select tag. Since you set the id of both to `""`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Show the generated HTML

Comment: @Tintin81 Why do you need a select box as the menu? I'm certain you could just rework your UI design and get this to work.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: The generated options are fairly simple: `<option value="http://localhost:3000/memberships">Membership</option>`

Comment: @MrDanA: Client order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing is submitting the form which does not process as a redirection you would need an additional hook for the form `onsubmit` event to process the redirection but based on your concept this seems unnecessary .

How does this work:

```
$('form select').on('change', function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Or all in jQuery I believe you can use

```
$('form select').on('change', function() {
  $(location).attr('href',this.val());
});
```

Obviously this hook will apply to all `form select` DOM objects so I would suggest adding an `id` to the select like so (notice I dropped the form tag as it is not needed for functionality)

```
select_tag "navigation", options_for_select([["Memberships", memberships_url], ["Transactions", transactions_url]])

$('#navigation').on('change', function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

You could also simulate a redirect instead of a link click using

```
window.location.replace($(this).val());
```